# Can you recommend an excellent book or article about how to critique a journal article?

Tags: peer-review, books

I am a novice researcher.
I received an article to review, and I don't know very well how to critique such an article.
Can you recommend an excellent book (or other source of information) about how to critique a journal article?

Any recommendations are highly appreciated!

Comment: I'd be surprised if it exists. The potential audience is too small. Find info with a web search. Someone has probably blogged it.

Comment: The general procedure is simply to assess whether the paper is novel, correct, and well written. Since you’ve read many papers, the assumption is that you already essentially know how to assess these things.

Comment: It would help if you would add a discipline.  Still a quick Google search found https://authorservices.wiley.com/Reviewers/journal-reviewers/how-to-perform-a-peer-review/step-by-step-guide-to-reviewing-a-manuscript.html

Comment: I hope my edit still captures your intent here. If not, you can roll it back to your original.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE! This site works differently from other online Q&A sites. This particular question might be off-topic because it asks for opinions on a preference for recommendations; it is not a fact-based question. See https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for details: "broad, open-ended, or primarily opinion-based questions, which are not a good fit for the Stack Exchange format in general". You might want to ask a question like this on ResearchGate or Quora. Feel free to ask other questions with more objective answers.

Answer (score 1):

Not a book, but an article:

"[Ten Simple Rules for Reviewers](https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.0020110)" by Philip E. Bourne and Alon Korngreen (PLoS Computational Biology vol. 2, issue 9, e110, September 2006)

DOI: 10.1371/journal.pcbi.0020110

1. Do Not Accept a Review Assignment unless You Can Accomplish the Task in the Requested Timeframe—Learn to Say No
2. Avoid Conflict of Interest
3. Write Reviews You Would Be Satisfied with as an Author
4. As a Reviewer You Are Part of the Authoring Process
5. Be Sure to Enjoy and to Learn from the Reviewing Process
6. Develop a Method of Reviewing That Works for You
7. Spend Your Precious Time on Papers Worthy of a Good Review
8. Maintain the Anonymity of the Review Process if the Journal Requires It
9. Write Clearly, Succinctly, and in a Neutral Tone, but Be Decisive
10. Make Use of the “Comments to Editors”

Answer (score 0):

Not a book, but a blog post

[Tips and advice when you review a scientific paper](http://www.bestoun.net/tips-and-advices-when-you-review-a-scientific-paper/)

Gives quite a few tips on reviewing a paper.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I'd suggest Chapter 6 of the following book:

Rugg, G., & Petre, M. (2020). Reading and sense-making. In G. Rugg & M. Petre (Eds.), The Unwritten Rules of PHD Research (3rd ed., pp. 71–89). Open University Press.

For systematic literature reviews, I'd go for the checklist in the Appendix of the following paper:

Moher, D., Liberati, A., Tetzlaff, J., & Altman, D. G. (2009). Preferred reporting items for systematic reviews and meta-analyses: the PRISMA statement. PLoS Medicine, 6(7), e1000097. https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pmed.1000097